# @Viewport @media use for input type?

Tags: javascript, html5, css3, responsive-webdesign, media

I've searched high and low for some way to setup my HTML5/CSS3 for various devices. Going by screen resolution isn't the best route because some times the screen size of one device is the same as another [e.g. my chrome book runs at 1280x800 and my android tablet runs at 1280x800] I'd want the website to look different for the tablet because it has touch capabilities meaning I can build a more "app like" design for that that I wouldn't want for my chrome book.

I've thought about the landscape vs portrait but that still doesn't get me there. @viewport and @media screen works to some degree as I can code for a browser vs mobile browsers but even the new iPhone/iPad has a higher resolutions than some legacy monitors.

I am truly stumped as to how I could code in a way to detect input type and load appropriately. (ie if touch display X if keyboard display Y)

Comment: Please refer to the answer to this StackOverflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11387805/touchscreen-media-queries

Comment: best answer I've found yet. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: I'm closing this question because it appears that an answer was found on StackOverflow and this question is three years old and has not attracted good answers here.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes
Maybe it can help you.

Comment: Welcome to Pro Webmasters! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.